# pagination problem - unable to understand the log

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I can't see any error in the log I got, but only 108 elements are scraped although there are far more items to be scraped. So, I guess it can be a problem with pagination. But no idea how to solve it.

Here is the shortened log I got:

```
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: digi_allbooks)
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 09:44:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 120, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 60, 'BOT_NAME': 'digi_allbooks', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'xml', 'FEED_URI': '99-08-01.xml', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'digi_allbooks.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['digi_allbooks.spiders']}
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 2583fc44c0155dc4
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'digi_allbooks.middlewares.UserAgentRotatorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-22 11:59:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/> from <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book>
2020-10-22 11:59:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/> (referer: None)
2020-10-22 11:59:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/>
{'title': 'کتاب 1984 اثر جورج اورول نشر شاهدخت پاییز', 'star': 4.6, 'discounted_percent': 69, 'discounted_price': 19900, 'original_price': 65000, 'discounted_amount': 45100, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2824939/کتاب-1984-اثر-جورج-اورول-نشر-شاهدخت-پاییز'}

2020-10-22 11:59:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?sortby=4&pageno=2>
{'title': 'کتاب ملت عشق اثر الیف شافاک', 'star': 4.4, 'discounted_percent': 43, 'discounted_price': 39900, 'original_price': 70000, 'discounted_amount': 30100, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-565603/کتاب-ملت-عشق-اثر-الیف-شافاک'}
2020-10-22 11:59:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?sortby=4&pageno=2>
{'title': 'کتاب زنان زیرک اثر شری آرگو', 'star': 4.5, 'discounted_percent': 16, 'discounted_price': 29400, 'original_price': 35000, 'discounted_amount': 5600, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-413298/کتاب-زنان-زیرک-اثر-شری-آرگو'}
2020-10-22 11:59:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-22 11:59:21 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored xml feed (108 items) in: 99-08-01.xml
2020-10-22 11:59:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2133,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 270896,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 8, 29, 21, 140213),
 'item_scraped_count': 108,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 113,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 8, 29, 17, 564090)}
2020-10-22 11:59:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And here is my shortened spider:

```
class AllbooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'allbooks'
    allowed_domains = ['www.digikala.com']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url= 'https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book',
            callback= self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        original_price=0
        
        try:
            for product in response.xpath("//ul[@class='c-listing__items js-plp-products-list']/li"):
                title= product.xpath(".//div/div[2]/div/div/a/text()").get()
                if product.xpath(".//div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/del/text()"):
                    original_price= int(str(product.xpath(".//div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/del/text()").get().strip()).replace(',', ''))
                    discounted_amount= original_price-discounted_price
                else:
                    original_price= print("not available")
                    discounted_amount= print("not available") 
                yield{
                    'title':title,
                    'discounted_amount': discounted_amount
                    }
             next_page= response.xpath('//*[@class="c-pager__item"]/../following-sibling::*//@href').extract_first()
             if next_page:
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
         except AttributeError:
             logging.error("The element didn't exist")
```

Can you help me to understand what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your next page link selector.
Your current code finds the first pagination link that is not currently active and then follows the one after it.

As a result, these are the links your spider tries to follow:

```
https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?sortby=4&pageno=3
https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?sortby=4&pageno=2
javascript:
```

One way to fix this is following the link after the *active* one (`@class="c-pager__item is-active"`).

Another way, resulting in simpler code, is following *every* pagination link and letting the dupefilter do its job:

```
for link in response.css(".c-pager__item"):
    yield response.follow(link)
```